# What is the analogous of a Google Cloud Project in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

According to Google, "you can think of a Google Cloud project as a virtual container for data, code, configuration, and services." Amazon Accounts seem to be a bit more than that. What is the analogous of a Google Cloud Project in AWS?

Answer (score 3):

**The AWS Account**.

Unfortunately, AWS does not support the concept of project isolation. There is no project entity that is distinct from the account entity.